# Categorical characterization of quasi-compact schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory

I would like to know if it is possible to characterize the property "quasi-compact" in the category of schemes by means of a pure categorical language. This would imply in particular that every equivalence of categories $\text{Sch} \to \text{Sch}$ preserves quasi-compact schemes. Together with Jonathan's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65506/infinite-products-exist-only-for-affine-schemes), this would answer affirmatively my [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65506/infinite-products-exist-only-for-affine-schemes) about the rigidity of the category of schemes, at least over a field $k$.

For example the property of being empty is categorical, because it just says that the scheme is initial. The terminal scheme is $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, so this is also categorical. Further examples of categorical properties or schemes: Spectra of fields, the underlying set of a scheme (in particular surjective morphisms), connected schemes, $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, and much more, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56887/rigidity-of-the-category-of-schemes). The usual definition of quasi-compact involves open immersions, which are, a priori, not categorical.

Comment: Related: http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/compact+object

Comment: @Qiaochu: The same nlab article shows that even for topological spaces this does not give the correct notion. It is better suited for algebraic categories.

Comment: I remember that the proper monomorphisms are the closed immersions and I thought that there was a similar story for open immersions but I've forgotten it. For properness you might be able to use some valuative criterion, but in this arguably pathological situation where maps aren't of finite type and schemes aren't noetherian perhaps anything can happen.

Comment: How about this? If $A\to X$ is a closed immersion then the corresponding open immersion is the terminal example of a map $Y\to X$ such that $A\times_XY$ is empty. 

Comment: Open/closed immersions are the étale/proper monomorphisms, but every definition of étale/proper uses some finiteness condition which is - a priori - not categorical.

Comment: Also remark that the valuative criterion is only categorical if we were able to show that a) quasiseparated schemes, b) spectra of valuation rings are categorical. 

Comment: @Martin: There's a functorial characterization of "locally of finite presentation" in EGA IV-8, and locally f.p. + formally \'etale + radicial = open immersion.

Comment: @Akhil: I know this EGA stuff. This uses affine schemes as test objects and is therefore not categorical. Unless you give me a categorical definition of affine schemes within the category of schemes, which would make me very, very happy ;-) 

Comment: @Martin: I wonder if your goal of reducing many (all?) concepts in scheme theory to purely categorical terms is unrealizable.  Consider Tannakian categories as an analogy: although every bit of the important algebra of (affine algebraic) group representations can be captured by the rigid tensor category formalism, we cannot give an "intrinsic" description of Rep(G), avoiding all mention of vector spaces: the fiber functor is a necessary part of the data.  Without it we can't distinguish categories actually equivalent to some Rep(G) from those merely sharing the formal properties. (continued)

Comment: (continued) It's not just that Rep(G) minus the vector spaces has automorphisms as a category but also that the collection of all Tannakian categories itself forms a category equivalent to that of affine pro-algebraic groups; if you forget the fiber functors, you don't just get extra automorphisms or 2-automorphisms, you also get extra objects (rigid tensor categories).  If you use tensor functors to vector bundles on some scheme X as the fiber functor, you will get some category of sheaves of groups on X locally equivalent to G.  (continued)

Comment: (continued) It seems to me that categorifying schemes will have the same issue, because affine schemes play a similarly definitive role as an undefined primitive concept.  If you do want to go this route, you might consider looking for a reconstruction theorem giving back the ring A from the category-plus-other-data Schemes/A, making sure that your category of categories-plus-data is equivalent to that of rings.  If this is possible, it will clarify the extent to which categorical information *does* define schemes.  (continued)

Comment: (continued) However, I think that specifying affine schemes may be necessary from the outset.  Even the most intrinsic definitions of, say, "open immersion" seem to rely on affine test schemes: either you base change the map in question to all affines and use the Zariski topology, or you use rings with nilpotent ideals to test for formal smoothness of a (categorically defined) monomorphism.  Given what I wrote above, I think you should consider this to be an emergent property of using affine schemes as your "fiber functor", along with all other pesky topological notions.

Comment: @Ryan: Just because my question cannot be answered within the usual realm of algebraic geometry or other theories, this does not mean that it cannot be answered at all. I know all these basics about schemes which you repeat, but we cannot use them here at all. This does not mean that I don't appreciate them! By the way, I do not want to define every scheme-theoretic notion in categorical terms, but enough in order to show that the category of schemes is rigid. It may be argued that this is a unnatural question, but this may be discussed per E-Mail.

Comment: Another remark: The category of schemes can be constructed categorically from the category of rings (-> Yves Dier, Categories of Commutative Algebras; the key step is to define localizations of rings with the help of so-called codisjunctors). Rigidity would be answered if there is a converse, i.e. the category of affine schemes can be constructed categorically from the category of schemes. 

Answer (score 4):

(This is a paraphrased version of something I learned from BCnrd. Consequently I'm posting it as a CW answer.)

There is currently no known useful criterion for quasi-compactness from the functor of points.  Nonetheless "locally of  finite presentation" does have one (cf. EGA IV-8.14).

This means in particular that to check for properness via the valuative criterion (which is purely functorial, of course), the extra steps of ensuring finite type need additional work---*locally* of finite type can be checked thanks to the criterion just listed, but one also wants quasi-compactness.

So in practice what one often does is to take something known to be quasi-compact (e.g. a concrete scheme) and surject this onto the moduli space in question. Surjectiveness can be checked functorially (using the spectra of large algebraically closed fields). This is the main way of establishing that an Artin stack or algebraic space is quasi-compact.

Comment: Okay, but I don't see any connection with my question. The functor of points only adresses affine-valued points, whereas in my question it is "available" on the whole category of schemes.

Comment: @Martin: Ah, ok, I see I may have misunderstood the question. Sorry for the confusion -- said confusion was entirely mine, and not BCnrd's.